# WMI Windows Management Instrumentation on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, remote, administration

Is there a tool for accessing windows'wmi interface?

I know once there was wmic-client (hardy) but it has been removed. 
I'd like to administrate some windows machines remotely trough shell: i.e. remove software.

At least does someone knows if there is a psexec or similar utility?

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps. [WMI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/WMI)

Comment: Not exactly. I mean, it is something like rsh to execute commands to a remote computer.  
Like `wmic -U Administrator%mysecret //192.168.5.9 "Select WorkingSetSize from Win32_Process Where CommandLine like '%java.exe%'"`  

Look here:
[link](http://www.krenger.ch/blog/wmi-commands-from-linux/)

Comment: Details on the package's removal from Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wmi/+bug/359637 and from Debian: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=523638.  The bugs indicate that some of its functionality may be available through Samba 4, but doesn't elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

There's a procedure, I'm testing right not if works:

http://techedemic.com/2012/11/05/installing-wmic-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts-64-bit-desktop/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: and there is an article for [Ubuntu 14](http://techedemic.com/2014/09/17/installing-wmic-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit/)  as well.